# What are some Facebook Fans API alternatives?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I was using the /{object_id}/members/{member_id} API to check if a particular member liked a particular page. This stopped working a few days ago, it always returns an empty array. Are there any alternate ways of getting this information?

For example: http://graph.facebook.com/248760105136026/members/1215104 returns {data:[]}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fairly simple and there's a few ways:

- Query the userid's likes `/me/likes` and see if that page is on that list.
- Decode the `signed_requests` object.  It has a page object property that has a liked boolean property.
- Via FQL and check to ensure it returns that row: `SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=PAGEID`